# What is the opposite of the suffix -cide?

Tags: antonyms, suffixes

All the words ending with the suffix -cide explain what was killed. Is there a suffix for what did the killing? Killed by hammer, killed by fall, etc.?

Thanks.

Comment: A joke that people from Liverpool won't find funny - Q: What's half-way between murder and suicide? A: Merseyside!

Comment: Instrument is not the opposite!

Comment: The decision to close this question as duplicate seems to be based solely on its title. The body of the question makes it clear that the title does not express very well what the OP has in mind; when that is taken into account, it turns out that the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: How about ***-ing***?  A stabbing, a bludgeoning, a knifing, a hanging, a bombing ...